# Pandas: How to use groupby and max() to select the rows with max date?

Tags: python, pandas

How to use `groupby` and `max` function to filter the results by the latest date and unique customer_id? Also,the`NaN` data are involved.

Dataframe: (*the datatype of `date` is datetime64[ns])

```
customer_id | stock_id|    date     |  Type  |
------------+---------+-------------+--------|
1           |   112   |  2012-12-05 |  Fish  |
2           |   211   |  2015-08-15 |  Meat  |
3           |   313   |  2020-04-20 |  Milk  |
1           |   113   |  2013-12-30 |  Fruit |
1           |   114   |  2014-12-30 |  Snacks|
2           |   212   |  2017-09-21 |  Fish  |
4           |   411   |      NaT    |  Fruit |
5           |   511   |      NaT    |  Snacks|
```

Expected Output:

```
customer_id | stock_id|    datetime |  Type  |
------------+---------+-------------+--------|
1           |   114   |  2014-12-30 |  Snacks|
2           |   212   |  2017-09-21 |  Fish  |
3           |   313   |  2020-04-20 |  Milk  |
4           |   411   |      NaT    |  Fruit |
5           |   511   |      NaT    |  Snacks|
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: try: `df.groupby('customer_id',as_index=False).agg({'stock_id':'max','date':'max','Type':'last'})`

Comment: Next time, the latest date of that record is not located at the least, How can I solve it?

Comment: can a max datetime appear for a customer more than once?

Answer (score 4):

To keep all latest dates for each `customer`, use `groupby.transform` to calculate the `max` dates and then filter based on the `date` column:

```
df[df.groupby('customer_id').date.transform('max') == df.date]

   customer_id  stock_id        date    Type
2            3       313  2020-04-20    Milk
4            1       114  2014-12-30  Snacks
5            2       212  2017-09-21    Fish
6            4       411         NaT   Fruit
7            5       511         NaT  Snacks
```